# Scala efficiency

Tags: java, scala, coding-efficiency

I am interested on your views on Scala efficiency.  It seems that Scala (and other functional programming languages) trade efficiency for code writing efficiency.  The program below contains a test of a Scala program that contains an insertion sort in the style of both a pure functional approach and a more classic C++ approach.

As you can see from the output, the functional style is an order of magnitude less efficient than the C++ style.  Are there improvements in the functional style that I could make?

```
package Algorithms

case object Sorter {
 def mutableInsertSort(a: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
    var ar = a.toArray
    for (j<-1 to ar.size - 1) {
      val k = ar(j)
      var i = j
      while ((i>0) && (ar(i-1)) > k) {
        ar(i) = ar(i-1)
        i = i - 1
      }
      ar(i) = k
    }
    ar.toVector
  }

 def insertSort(a: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
    def immutableInsertSort(target: Vector[Int], i: Int): Vector[Int] = {
      if (i == target.size) target
      else { 
        val split = target.splitAt(i)    // immutable overhead
        val sorted = split._1.takeWhile(x=>x<target(i))
        val newTarget = sorted ++ Vector(target(i)) ++ split._1.slice(sorted.size, split._1.size) ++ split._2.tail  //last two segments are immutable overheads
        immutableInsertSort(newTarget, i + 1)   //immutable overhead
      }
    }
    immutableInsertSort(a, 1)
  }
}

object Sorting extends App {
  val a = (1 to 1000).toVector.map(x=>(math.random*2000).toInt)
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  Sorter.insertSort(a)
  println ("I" + (System.nanoTime - t1))
  val t2 = System.nanoTime
  Sorter.mutableInsertSort(a)
  println ("M" + (System.nanoTime - t2))
}
```

Comment: " It seems that Scala (and other functional programming languages) trade efficiency for code writing efficiency." This is not true.

Comment: In a pure functional approach, does it even matter which technique it's sorted with? `val t3 = a.sorted`

Answer (score 1):

This one is more natural a functional implementation, and is about 4 times slower than the mutable one. Note I ran the sorts 1000 times first to "warm up" the JVM. Running a sort of only 1000 items just once is fairly meaningless due to JIT overheads and so on.

```
def insertSort2(a: Seq[Int]):Seq[Int] = {
    def insertOne(b:Seq[Int], x:Int):Seq[Int] = {
       val (before, after) = b.span(_ < x)
       before ++ (x +: after)
    }
    a.foldLeft(Seq[Int]()) {insertOne}
}
```